# Problem with Selenium FindElements in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

This is probably a nooby question butI have used the other Selenium findElementBy and findElementsBy methods with no problems but using the **findElements** method causes a compile error ... Variable not defined with **By** highlighted in the line driver.FindElements(**By**.id(locator)). Any examples I have found look similar to my syntax. I would like to use this method as it returns an empty list if it fails to find.

```
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
Dim url As String
Dim ele As WebElement
Dim eles As WebElements
Dim locator As String

locator = "myId"
url = "https://myUrl"
driver.Get url
driver.Window.Maximize
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

eles = driver.FindElements(By.id(locator))
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
driver.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the syntax, but maybe try to add this at the beginning:

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.By
```

Comment: Sorry but not that familiar with Imports statement. I thought it was used in .Net not VBA.  Anyway tried it and complains stating  "Invalid outside procedure".  Also can only find java package on selenium.dev website.